# как сохранить полученное значение в переменную js

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
butt.onclick = function() {
    var val = document.getElementById('elem1').value;
    console.log(val);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="elem1" type="text" name="quantity" placeholder="Количество">
<input id="butt" type="button" value="Кнопка"/><br><br>
<div id="str"></div>
```

Если например пишу var zer=val;
console.log(zer);
то ошибку выдает

Comment: мне нужно будет использовать значение inputa в дальнейшем

Comment: т.е каким образом мне потом доставать эти значения,подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: где и когда в дальнейшем? вы попробуйте определиться в какой момент времени у вас какие фрагменты кода выполняются.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Comment: Я буду использовать эти значения для того, чтобы внести их в физические формулы

Comment: т.е вписываю текст в инпуты, нажимаю кнопку,допустим "выполнить" , и при нажатии введенные числа должны быть внесены в формулы.

Comment: Почему у вас onclick, а не onkeyup?  И зачем вы через простой javasript делаете, если подключаете jquery?

Comment: мне нужен onclick потому что.

Comment: @СергейВарфолеев "то ошибку выдает" - Такую - **ОШИБКА**?

Answer (score 2):

```js
const $button = document.getElementById('button');
const $input = document.getElementById('input');
const $output = document.getElementById('output');

$input.addEventListener(`input`, e => {
  $output.innerHTML = `Введено: ${e.target.value}`;
});

$button.addEventListener(`click`, e => {
  $output.innerHTML = `Получено: ${$input.value}`;
});
```

```html
<input id="input" type="number" name="quantity" placeholder="Количество">
<input id="button" type="button" value="Кнопка" /><br><br>
<div id="output"></div>
```